# How do I transforming code for PySpark or multiprocessing?

Tags: python, pyspark, multiprocessing

I apologize in advance for the poorly worded question..

I would like to split up the following computations with different processors. Using 1 processor is taking too long. I have access to 48 processors to split this process on.

Basically, every 2 hours I would like to scan log files for processes/tasks that ran on Airflow.   In order to find which folders need to be scanned, I use `bsh_cmd_find`.  The output gives me a path in the form of a string.. this path is added to a list, `paths`. Each path in the list is then open to see if `.log` files exsist in the folder. These log file paths are added to a new list called `files`.   There are still a lot of excess files, so I find the modification time of each file and filter it down to the previous 2 hours. This is all taking around ~10 minutes in total. The actual code that scans the logs is not needed for the context.

Is it possible to distribute this task using `PySpark` or `multiprocessing`? I don't have experience in either.

```
two_hours_ago = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(minutes=125)  ## using 125 for delay.


print("Running bash command to find processes that ran within the past 2 hours...")

## Setting modification time for 30 minutes
mtime = -2/24;

bsh_cmd_find = "find /home/storage/user/airflow/logs -maxdepth 3 -type d -mtime {0} -wholename *_*/[A-Za-z]*".format(mtime)

args = shlex.split(bsh_cmd_find)

for out in Popen(args,stdout = PIPE).stdout:
            out = out.decode("utf-8")  # Converting the output path from a byte to a string
            out = out.rstrip() # Removing trailing whitespace from the path string
            paths.append(out)

print("Extracting all the logs...")
#d = directories, f = files, r = roots
for path in paths:
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            if '.log' in file:
                files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

files = [i for i in files if 'dag_processor_manager' not in i]
files = [i for i in files if 'scheduler' not in i]

print("Extracting modification time of the logs...")
for f in files:
    mod_time = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(f))
    mod_time_list.append(mod_time)

tuple_list = list(zip(files, mod_time_list))

my_df = pd.DataFrame(tuple_list, columns = ['Files', 'Date'])

my_df = my_df[(my_df['Date'] >= two_hours_ago) & (my_df['Date'] <= current_time)]

files = my_df['Files'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible. You have tons of documentation online starting with the [spark official web site](https://spark.apache.org/).
I am not sure if you expect that someone would transform your code directly into something runable on spark, but it quite unlikely to happen.

Comment: No, my intention with the questions is IF it is possible with the type of task. I have no experience with Spark was wondering if the code I have is possible to be distributed via Spark. I dont need someone to do it for me.

Comment: And my answer is YES